# How to use a unique identifier for a set of buttons?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have broken my problem down to be simple. A guest can post a question and a host can answer them. When the host answers a question, for each question there is a text field with a submit answer button. For the host, there are x amount of buttons on a page at a given time depending on how many questions a guest posts.I am trying to target every submit answer button (that has the same identifier) with a confirm modal.
I have managed to target the first button, but for some reason every other button with the same identifier won't target. I also tried to do a for loop through the buttons and essentially wrap a for loop around the sweet alert Javascript to no avail.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/860p72Ld/) is what I tried. Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('.q_a');
  btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.id);
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: 'Confirm',
        text: 'Your question/answer will be publicly visible - it is not a private message. Are you sure you want to proceed?',
        buttons: [
          'No',
          'Yes, I am sure'
        ]
      })
      .then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm) {
          swal("Confirming...", {
            buttons: false,
          });
          btnSubmit.submit();
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Answer" class="q_a btn btn-success" id="q_a">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Answer" class="q_a btn btn-success" id="q_a">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ids should be unique. Try using class instead of id.

Comment: I am already using a class="q_a" for all the buttons. I thought it would work using the same class for all buttons, but it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Try this `var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('UnFollowUser');
 for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  
     buttons[i].click();`

Comment: I don't know where you get the questions from, but if they come from any kind of data storage, they should have an identifier value. Add this value to the `id` of the relevant inputs, or use a `data-` attribute

Comment: @Sami They do come from data (persistent) storage but targeting them only targets the first one. I have tried most ways I can think of.

Comment: @Hussam I tried this and still can't get it to work with my code when I loop through https://jsfiddle.net/au1q7fzr/

Comment: @StephenW oh, I misunderstood the problem at first. Added one way as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u should use  `document.querySelectorAll('.q_a')` instead of  `document.querySelector('.q_a')`, and then use `for of`to loop each target to bind event。`querySelector` just return the first matched dom.
just like:

```js
    const btnSubmits = document.querySelectorAll('.q_a');
    for(btn of btnSubmits){
     btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      ...
     })
   }
```

Comment: Whoops wrong link. Here is correct one https://jsfiddle.net/tLmaypde/ Tried it and it did not target or work.

Comment: @StephenW this worked https://jsfiddle.net/2tuzi/aLo5hv93/

Comment: Ahh, for of loop...I should have thought of that lol. Thanks so much. If you update your answer I would be glad to mark it as the answer as you solved the issue.

Comment: you are welcome@StephenW ,i Edited , and i think @sami's answer can also worked, and maybe better

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this, without looping all of the elements is to use jQuery to add the event listener. To do this, replace your

```
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
```

with

```
$('input.q_a').on('click', function(e){
```